# The Principle of Indifference, Discrete, and Continuous Distributions and the 6 / not 6 die.

Tags: probability

[Bertrand's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)) is an example that is cited to show that the Principle of Indifference doesn't work for continuous distributions. The dogma is that there are multiple ways to choose "uniform randomness" with continuous distributions and that the various ways aren't invariant in assigning probability.  For example the random radius and the random angle methods yield different results.

The dogma also is that discrete distributions are well behaved and you can apply the Principle of Indifference without problem. But are the discrete and continuous cases so different?

Let's say I have a normal 6 sized die spotted 1 to 6. What is the probability that I get a 6?

I can of course write down all the numbers thrown so so I get $53261352315...$ and so on. Since there are six digits each digit gets 1/6 probability.

But I could also write $\bar6\bar6\bar66\bar6\bar66\bar6...$ Now there are just two possible states and each should get 1/2.

*But common sense...* Well wait! What if the die was marked with a $6$ on one face and $\bar6$ on the other five? Who is to say that I shouldn't just look at the indication on the face of the die?

It just doesn't seem to me that the different between the discrete case and the continuous case is so "obviously obvious to the casual observer" anymore. In both cases if you don't use the "right" probability distributions for the real world system that you're trying to model then you get burned.

What am I missing?

Comment: With the six-sided die, there is a natural physical interpretation of what *uniform* means.  Perhaps less so for the question "will there be a sunrise tomorrow?" or for the chords in Bertrand's paradox

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @MikeHawk - Ok, fair enough. I added question "What am I missing?" to the post.

Comment: @Henry - Yes, but "natural" was supposed to be unambiguous in the discrete case. So for my die with $6$ & $\bar6$ it seems "natural" to just write down what I see. I have to analyze the problem more deeply to figure out that the probability is 1/6, which is exactly where Bertand's chord paradox gets you.

Comment: The natural interpretation @Henry had in mind is for the sides themselves to be equally likely to land face up. If they're not, what makes one side more likely? The fact you drew a $6$ on it?

Comment: @J.G. - On the 2nd version of the die I proposed that one face be marked $6$ and the other 5 faces be marked $\bar6$. So a face either comes up as $6$ or $\bar6$. Thus when you write down you observation you're not ignoring information on top face of the die. The whole point is that then you have to do a deeper analysis of the problem to understand the results. Of course it isn't so hard to do in the case of a six-sided die, but you still have to do a deeper analysis. The wrong analysis gets you into trouble.

Comment: @MaxW A deeper analysis? Like knowing you can't magically make one face more likely to land face-up by painting it? What if I recorded the face-down number by lying underneath your table, assuming it's made of glass? Do we each have a 50% chance of seeing $6$, guaranteeing the $6$ can't be one of the other four sides?

Comment: @J.G. - I think you missing the point that I'm trying to make. The probabilities for discrete distributions are supposed to be totally unambiguous. I'm trying to point out that such distributions are not totally unambiguous. Yes, they are easier to analyze, but that doesn't mean that no analysis is necessary.

Comment: @MaxW What do you mean by "supposed", or "unambiguous"? "Each side has probability $1/6$" is unambiguous, as is "This side has probability $1/2$, while the others each have probability $1/10$ until MaxW makes up some other answer". Basically, any choice of the probabiities as non-negative numbers summing to $1$ is "unambiguous". Besides that, discrete distributions don't owe you anything.

Comment: Two different experiments.  First experiment some other person rolls the dice and you just get the written results. You'll immediately know something is out of whack with your abstract model of the die as "6" or "not 6" being equal, but you won't know why. Second experiment you get to roll the die. Again you realize something is out of whack, then you can analyze the die and figure out that 5 sides have "not 6" and 1 side has a "6". Now you can appropriately revise your abstract model so it will agree with the concrete experiment. You could go a further in analysis and color the "not 6"'s.

Comment: To make my point differently, there are numerous references to computer programs being written to confirm each of Bertrand's models. However the random number generator (RNG) in any computer is quantized since the RNG can't generate a number small than the smallest floating point number that the computer system can handle. Thus although the program could generate more chords than any feasible runtime would allow, there are still only a finite number of chords possible.